# Coinbase Pro - Get Account Hold Pagination Requests

Tags: api, pagination

With reference to https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#get-account-history

HTTP REQUEST
GET /accounts//holds

I am struggling to produce python code to get the account holds via API pagination request and I could not find any example of implementing it.

Could you please advise me on how to proceed with this one?

Comment: You can find pagination specs here https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#pagination

Comment: Thank you for the link but I am struggling to interpret and translate that into python code.  Could you please give me guide?

Comment: For example, I tried to access holds but no avail.  Please advised.
# GET /accounts/<account_id>/holds
r2 = requests.get(api_url + 'accounts/holds', auth=auth)
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_normalize(r2.json()), orient='columns')
print(df2)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Coinbase Pro documentation](https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#pagination), pagination works like so (example with the [`holds`](https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#get-holds) endpoint):

```python
import requests

account_id = ...
url = f'https://api.pro.coinbase.com/accounts/{account_id}/holds'

response = requests.get(url)
assert response.ok

first_page = response.json()  # here is the first page
cursor = response.headers['CB-AFTER']

response = requests.get(url, params={'after': cursor})
assert response.ok

second_page = response.json()  # then the next one
cursor = response.headers['CB-AFTER']

# and so on, repeat until response.json() is an empty list
```

You should properly wrap this into helper functions or class, or, even better, [use an existing library](https://github.com/danpaquin/coinbasepro-python) and save dramatic time.